# Where and how should selected items be managed in a MVVM architecture?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, selection

I have a view that allows the user to select some data : some dates for example, and executes a command that needs these data.

So in my command I should have a reference to the selected date, but what is the best practice to make this date go to the ViewModel side where the command lives :

- to add a SelectedDate dependency property in the ViewModel and bind my view on it, and reference it in my command via "@this.SelectedDate" (with @this a reference to the current ViewModel),
- to let the view transmit it through the "parameter" of the "Execute" method of the command, and reference the date with "DateTime selectedDate = (DateTime)parameter;",
- any other solution...

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make `SelectedDate` a dependency property of the view model, absolutely.

I'd also make the command get the `SelectedDate` from the view model.  There's no reason for the view to know anything about that.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.
It definitely seems that the DP solution is the best.

Answer (score 1):

To the first part, Yes I think the SelectedDate should be an (INotify) property of your ViewModel.

I don't have a strong opinion on where your Command should obtain this information, I think the property is OK.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

For me the main advantage of the DP approach is simplicity : the view simply fills the DPs and the command has a direct access to its data.

With the second approach the view has to "serialize" data to check for command state and to execute the command, and the command has to "unserialize" data on its side.

Answer (score 1):

The **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** shows a way to handle the selected item with MVVM: The ViewModel has a 'SelectedBook' property which is bound to the View.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting input which confirms the above assertions.